# How to pass value from Angular unit test into dynamic HTML tag

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'd like to pass `"test"` value within my unit test to `nodeName` and `nodeDisplayName` in this dynamic HTML tag in order to display this checkbox.

my unit test:

```
it('checkbox is appearing', () => {
        const nodes= [{
          nodeDisplayName: "test",
          nodeName: "test"
        }];
         //  pass value to HTML code

        const checkbox= fixture.debugElement.query((de) => {
          return de.nativeElement.id === 'test';
        });
        expect(checkbox).not.toBeNull();
});
```

my HTML tag:

```
<div *ngFor="let node of nodes let i = index" class="multipleNodes">
    <label class="nodebtn bold" [id]=node.nodeName ngbTooltip="{{node.nodeDisplayName}}" tooltipClass="nodeTooltip">
         <input type="checkbox" attr.for="{{node}}" value="{{i}}" name="{{i}}" (change)="checkboxChange($event)">
                  {{node.nodeName}}
    </label>
</div>
```

expect HTML output (inspect):

```
<div class="multipleNodes">
      <label class="nodebtn bold active" tooltipClass="nodeTooltip" ng-reflect-tooltip-class="nodeTooltip" ng-reflect-ngb-tooltip="test" id="test">
            <input type="checkbox" for="[object Object]" value=0 name=0 >
                      " test "
      </label>
</div>
```

The `n.name` and `n.displayName` are actually from the previous page by clicking the particular element then send to this page, but I want to test only `'test'` element.

the relevant piece of code in my `.ts` file:

```
@Input() data;
 ngOnInit() {
if (this.data.process === 'click') {
        this.setLinear = true;
        this.nodes = this.data.nodes.map((n) => {
          return {
            nodeName: n.name,
            nodeDisplayName: n.displayName,
          };
        });
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your ```component.ts``` relevant for the template you shared?

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig just updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either mock your import (which I would personally prefer) or update the component property after the onInit is finished.

It is important to understand, that `ngOnInit()` gets triggered during the first `fixture.detectChanges()` call in your describe block.

If you are using the first approach in mocking the import, you need to make sure this is done before calling `fixture.detectChanges`. Usually when a test is generated by the cli there is a `fixture.detectChanges` inside the beforeEach cycle. That one would need to be removed and in every `it` you would need to call that explicitly whenever the setup is finished.

Input mock:

```
it('checkbox is appearing', () => {
     const nodes = [{
              nodeDisplayName: "test",
              nodeName: "test"
            }]
     component.nodes = nodes; //in case nodes is public
     (component as any).nodes = nodes //in case nodes is private
     fixture.detectChanges();

     const checkbox= fixture.debugElement.query((de) => {
        return de.nativeElement.id === 'test';
     });
     expect(checkbox).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Changes after onInit already finished (imho not the best way):

```
it('checkbox is appearing', () => {
     fixture.detectChanges();
     const data = {
          process: 'click',
          nodes: [{
              nodeDisplayName: "test",
              nodeName: "test"
            }]
         }
     component.data = data;
     fixture.detectChanges();

     const checkbox= fixture.debugElement.query((de) => {
        return de.nativeElement.id === 'test';
     });
     expect(checkbox).not.toBeNull();
});
```